# Share file audio via WhatsApp

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipa, whatsapp

This is a code for image sharing via WhatsApp.
But i can not understand how to modify it to send the audio file.
If anyone knows me can write modified? Please.

```
- (IBAction)Share:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){
    UIImage * iconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NAMEIMAGE.jpeg"];
    NSString * savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

   [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
   _documentationInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
   _documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";    
   _documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;    

   [_documentationInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];
} 
else {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Errore" message:@"Sul tuo dispositivo non è installato WhatsApp." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
  }
}
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL
usingDelegate: (id ) interactionDelegate {
self.documentationInteractionController =    
[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

return self.documentationInteractionController;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){

    //UIImage * iconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myphoto.jpg"];
    NSString * savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.waa"];

    savePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myaudio" ofType:@"mp3"];

    //[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
    _documentationInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
    _documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.audio";
    _documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;

    [_documentationInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];
}
else {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Errore" message:@"Sul tuo dispositivo non è installato WhatsApp." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: It is usually a good idea to include some explanation of how the code answers the problem in addition to just bare code.

Comment: It was only added a line of code:

savePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myaudio" ofType:@"mp3"];

Comment: Audios being sent if they are in main bundle. I am facing issue while taking audio from music library and send to whatsapp. audio is fetched copied and whats app is called. WhatsApp shows progress and in the end audio failed.
audios are mp3. Any Help!!

Comment: Path of file: (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9FE7FD43-6521-4E9E-A400-21C9FF03EE27/Documents/AahistaAahistaOSTDramaonHumTV.waa) 
Tried with mp3 and waa extensions.